# NSDateFormatter causing crash when the date entered is the last day of the month in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am having this weird issue getting an NSDate from a string in which if the date entered is the last day of the month (ex: 2016-3-31), the application crashes with "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value." Here is the NSDate extension I am using to implement this:

```
extension NSDate {
convenience
init(dateString:String) {
    let dateStringFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateStringFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    dateStringFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")


            let d = dateStringFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)!
            self.init(timeInterval:0, sinceDate:d)
    }
}
```

It crashes at the line:

```
let d = dateStringFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)!
```

which I assume means it is not able to make the string into an NSDate. However it only happens when the date is the final day of the month. If I change the string entered, for example, from "2016-3-31 02:00:00" to "2016-3-30 02:00:00" it runs just fine. If anyone can help me out with this, it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: This code works fine. The problem ended up being in the code I was using to calculate the input string, which was adding 1 to the day. I also changed this to an "if let" statement to avoid future crashes caused by similar oversights. As it may be of use to others, here is the code I used for that:

```
    if let d = dateStringFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)  {
    self.init(timeInterval:0, sinceDate:d)
    } else {
        let d = dateStringFormatter.dateFromString("2017-12-15 00:00:00")
        self.init(timeInterval:0, sinceDate:d!)
    }
```

Comment: works fine. please figure out if the input you get when it crashes is different than you showed it here

Comment: Yes you are right. It ended up being an error in the input that I somehow overlooked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm - running your code with both provide strings in the Playground works perfectly.

One thing you might check is that somehow your string formatting isn't bugged somewhere else, because this code looks good, and the error indicates it wasn't able to generate `d`.

Comment: Thank you. You were right. I reviewed my other code and found out that it was adding 1 to the day and it was coming out as 2016-3-32.

Comment: You're welcome. This is also an example of how dangerous `!` is in Swift, and why `if let` is a great idea.